# How to I determine whether a character is valid-for/rendered-in html?

Tags: python, html

Some characters, such as ordinal 22 or 8, don't display in html (using chrome, for example when copy-and-pasting them into this 'Ask question' editor; I am assuming utf-8). How do I determine which characters are valid html, and of the valid, which are rendered?

A table/reference would be helpful (I couldn't find one by google-ing), but preferably I need a set of rules or a solution that can be implemented in python.

Comment: This really depends on the font and the document's character encoding. If you're talking about *truly* illegal characters, there's a simple list of them on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Illegal_characters

Comment: Perfect. So that explains why 22 and 8 weren't accepted, they're illegal. Easy enough to code myself from those rules.

Answer (score 0):

As answered as a comment by [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender), from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Illegal_characters):

> HTML forbids[8] the use of the characters with Universal Character
>   Set/Unicode code points
>
> - 0 to 31, except 9, 10, and 13 (C0 control characters)
> - 127 (DEL character)
> - 128 to 159 (x80 – x9F, C1 control characters)
> - 55296 to 57343 (xD800 – xDFFF, the UTF-16 surrogate halves)
>
> The Unicode standard also forbids:
>
> - 65534 and 65535 (xFFFE – xFFFF), non-characters, related to xFEFF, the byte order mark.
>
> These characters are not even allowed by reference. That is, you
>   should not even write them as numeric character references. However,
>   references to characters 128–159 are commonly interpreted by lenient
>   web browsers as if they were references to the characters assigned to
>   bytes 128–159 (decimal) in the Windows-1252 character encoding. This
>   is in violation of HTML and SGML standards, and the characters are
>   already assigned to higher code points, so HTML document authors
>   should always use the higher code points. For example, for the
>   trademark sign (™), use ™, not ™.
>
> The characters 9 (tab), 10 (linefeed), and 13 (carriage return) are
>   allowed in HTML documents, but, along with 32 (space) are all
>   considered "whitespace".[9] The "form feed" control character, which
>   would be at 12, is not allowed in HTML documents, but is also
>   mentioned as being one of the "white space" characters – perhaps an
>   oversight in the specifications. In HTML, most consecutive occurrences
>   of white space characters, except in a  block, are interpreted as
>   comprising a single "word separator" for rendering purposes. A word
>   separator is typically rendered a single en-width space in European
>   languages, but not in all the others.

Answer (score 0):

What is a valid character in HTML depends on your definition for “HTML” and “valid”. Different HTML versions have different rules for formally valid characters, and they may have characters that are valid but not recommended. Moreover, there are general policies such as favoring Normalization Form C; though not part of HTML specifications, such policies are often regarded as relevant to HTML, too.

What is rendered (and how) depends on the browser, the style sheets of the HTML document, and available fonts in the user’s computer. Moreover, not all characters are rendered as such. For example, in normal HTML content, any contiguous sequence of whitespace characters is treated as equivalent to a single space character.

So the answer is really “It depends.” Consider asking a much more targeted practical question to get a more targeted answer.